# How do I list the network-scoped alias for a running container?

Tags: docker

How do I list the network-scoped alias for a running container? You can create alias for a docker container using the command referenced below, but how do I see the aliases assigned once the env. is running? `docker network inspect` does not seem to list them?

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_inspect/

Answer (score 0):

`docker inspect <id>` of the container ID will show you the network aliases under "Networks"